# Roots to the quartic equation, $(x+1)^2+(x+2)^3+(x+3)^4=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Solving with Mathematica gives me the four roots, $$x=-4,-2,\dfrac{-7\pm\sqrt5}{2}$$ Is there some trick to solving this that doesn't involve expanding and/or factoring by grouping?

Comment: Still expanding, but let $u=x+2$.

Comment: Yes, that simplifies the problem nicely, at least making it easier to find one root. But without knowing that $x=-2$ is a root, how could I arrive at that sort of substitution? What would lead me to believe that would help?

Comment: To test for rational roots you only need to know the leading and the constant coefficients. The leading coefficient is the leading coefficient of $(x+3)^4$, which is $x^4$. And the constant coefficient is obtained by putting $x=0$. $1^2+2^3+3^4-2$. After testing the divisors of these coefficients you get the roots $-4$ and $-2$. Having those roots we only need the product and sum of the remaining roots. The product is the previous constant term divided by $(-4)\cdot(-2)$. The sum of all the roots is next to the leading coefficient. This we can also compute without expanding.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to use the rational root theorem, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: There is not enough symmetry here,  but in general it can be useful to expand about the "middle" term.

Comment: If nothing else, wouldn't you rather deal with $(u+1)^4$ rather than $(x+3)^4$? The substitution $u=x+2$ makes this term a little easier to deal with, it makes the middle term _very_ easy to deal with, and it makes no significant difference in the difficulty of the first term. It would be the first thing I would think to try even before noticing how easily it enables getting the root $x=-2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$[(x+1)^2-1]+(x+2)^3+(x+3)^4-1^4$$
$$=x(x+2)+(x+2)^3+[\{(x+3)^2-1\}\{(x+3)^2+1\}]$$
$$=x(x+2)+(x+2)^3+[(x+4)(x+2)\{(x+3)^2+1\}]$$

and 
$$[(x+1)^2-3^2]+(x+2)^3+2^3+(x+3)^4-1^4$$

$$=(x+4)(x-2)+\{(x+2)+2\}[(x+2)^2-2(x+2)+2^2]+[(x+4)(x+2)\{(x+3)^2+1\}]$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Write
$$(x + 3 - 2)^2 + (x+3 - 1)^3 + (x+3)^4 = 2$$

Let $y = x+3$ then

$$p(y) = y^2 - 4y + 4 + y^3 - 3y^2 + 3y -1 + y^4 = 2 \implies p(y) =y^4 + y^3 -2y^2 - y +1 = 0 $$

Notice that $1$ and $-1$ are  roots of $p(y)$.

Answer (score 2):

Although the substitution $y=x+2$ works well, I would first try $y=x+3$, which avoids having to expand the highest power (quartic) term and leads to $$y^4+y^3-2y^2-y+1=0$$This yields two roots $y=\pm 1$ to the rational root theorem. Or alternatively to the observation that $$y^4+y^3-2y^2-y+1=(y^4+y^3-y^2)-(y^2+y-1)=(y^2-1)(y^2+y-1)$$

A second thought would be to spot the even powers $(x+1)^2, (x+3)^4$, and to see that the minimum value of the sum of these for integer $x$ is $2$, which would lead to spotting the root $x=-2$.

Comment: Same thought here. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Set $y=x+2$. The equation rewrites as:
$$(y-1)^2+y^3+(y+1)^3==2\iff y(y^3+5y^2+7y^+2)=0$$
The second factor has an integer root: $-2$, hence the factorisation:
$$y^3+5y^2+7y +2=(y+2)(y^2+3y+1).$$
Finally, the roots (in $y$) are: $0, -2, \dfrac{-3\pm\sqrt 5}{2} $, whence the roots of the initial equation:
$$ \Bigl\{ -2,-4, \frac{-7\pm\sqrt 5}{2}\Bigr\}.$$